# Firebase console-Compose notification- Target tag not show in single device option

Tags: android, firebase

My task is specific android device sending image notification. But my firebase console is not show in SINGLE DEVICE option.

Comment: not able to understand your que

Comment: i am send the push notification for specific android device with image using upon firebase.

Answer (score 0):

follow this step for send notification to single device/user

open firebase console-> select your application-> select cloud messaging-> new notification -> fill Notification title and Notification text -> click on send text message.

When you click on send send text message it asking for add FCM resigtration token add your fcm token(you can add multiple token here for multiple device [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlSkg.jpg))

Comment: but,this is only send the text naveen sir.but,i needed to send with images on push notification.